# How to provide path to service key file in index.js file, for firebase-auth?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to give the path of serviceAccountKey.json file in my index.js file because I am unable to register the new users and uploading the DP of logged in users(the users can logg in if the account is created from the firebase manually) because of the error `400`. I pasted the serviceAccountKey.json file in (Firebase) functions folder, which is different from public folder and my Index.js file is also in the same folder (functions folder).

The image describes the directory of my project

[image: Directory of the Project]

I am giving the path as

`var serviceAccount = require("/serviceAccountKey.json");`

Okay, so for more details, I am pasting the complete code of Index.js file-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');


var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("/serviceAccountKey.json");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "I DON'T THINK IT IS COMPULSORY TO TYPE URL IN STACKOVERFLOW"
});


const app = express();
app.get('/', (request, response)=>{

     response.send(index.html);

});


exports.app=functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And I am getting the error-

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '/serviceAccountKey.json'
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a file in the current path you can do it like:

```
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")
```

Also I would recommend you to take a look at the docs for paths here: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: hey, thanx, the site has been deployed successfully, but I can't still register the new user. I am getting the following error
    {"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","errors":[{"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Can you please help me in this case

Comment: that sounds like a permissions problem, are you sure you are using the right keys for Firebase?

Comment: Yes I am using the right api key, but still it is getting that error